# How to bypass client-side http response to show hidden items in json field?

Tags: http, api, json

If I send a HTTP request to an API, I get the following as one of the fields of the JSON response.

> "item_count": 20

The number 20 is capped on the client side browser and does not show the complete number of items on the list. For example, suppose it has 36 items in the list but the response will always cap out at 20 and not show the remaining 16 items. How do I go around this to find the total number of items in the list from the response?

The HTTP headers used to send the request is as following:

```
POST /game/user/get_profile_by_username/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
Content-Length: 26
X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/22.0.0.209
Origin: http://www.example.com
ERROR_STATUS_CODE: 200
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.example.com/flash_client/play.swf?q=401
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection: close
```

Comment: More info is required.

Comment: Did you have a look at the actual response JSON? Are there really more than 20 items? You might have to supply different parameters in order to get the remaining items.